# How to insert word count as a string in a file?

Tags: awk, wc

I am trying to insert a line at the beginning of a file named text.txt that tells how many lines were in the text. Like:

```
35764
43587
12905
13944
```

After using the command, it should redirect the file into a textwc.txt, as

```
4

35764
43587
12905
13944
```

I tried to define a variable as a `wc -l` and tried to recall it into a `awk`, but i haven't achieve anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following in `awk`.

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < Input_file)" 'FNR==1{print lines} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With 2 times reading Input_file try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{count++;next} FNR==1{print count} 1' Input_file Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `tac` + `awk` solution.

```
tac Input_file | awk '1;END{print FNR}' | tac
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** In case your Input_file is NOT huge then try following.

```
awk '{val=(val?val ORS:"")$0}  END{print FNR ORS val}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can like this:

```
sed "1i $(wc -l < text.txt)" text.txt
```

Output:

```
4
35764
43587
12905
13944
```

Count number of line then insert to the first line using sed
In case you want a empty line after #count, edit the inserted text

```
sed "1i $(wc -l < text.txt)\n" text.txt
```